# Qt signal mapping

Tags: c++, qt

I understand that we could use QSignalMapper to collect a set of parameterless signals, and re-emit them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal.

But could we do the reverse?
For example, is it possible to achieve:

```
connect(control,startVehicle(0),vehcileList[0],startReceived());
connect(control,startVehicle(1),vehcileList[1],startReceived());
connect(control,startVehicle(2),vehcileList[2],startReceived());
```

instead of having 3 different signals from control as

```
startVehicle_1();
startVehicle_2(); 
startVehicle_3();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way:

```
connect(control, SIGNAL(startVehicle(int)), this, SLOT(startReceived(i)));

//in startReceived(i) slot
vehcileList[i]->startReceived();
```

Comment: The thing is, each vehicle is under a different thread (it's a multi-agent simulation program), and they have something like QTimer with them. So I can only start them from their own thread. Thus, by just calling vehicleList[i]->startReceived() from one thread is not working...

Comment: You can use `QTimer::singleShot(0, vehcileList[i], SLOT(startReceived()))` to safely invoke a slot in another thread.